# Massive holding open of TCP/IP sockets

Tags: sockets, tcp

I would like to create a server infrastructure that allows 500 clients to connect all at the same time and have an indefinite connection. The plan is to have clients connect to TCP/IP sockets on the server and have them stay connected, with the server sending out data to clients randomly and clients sending data to the server randomly, similar to a small MMOG, but with scarcely any data. I came up with this plan in comparison to TCP polling every 15-30 seconds from each client.

My question is, in leaving these connections open, will this cause a massive sum of server bandwidth usage at idle? Is this the best approach without getting into the guts of TCP?

Comment: FYI: it is possible to sustain > [2 millions concurrent sockets](http://blog.whatsapp.com/index.php/2012/01/1-million-is-so-2011/) that makes 500 rather small, not massive.

Comment: In my experience, 'Massive' is around 36k connections, as these are the numbers seen on a single server in multi-server worlds. I wanted to start with 500 to be modest, but 15k is more realistic for the final product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP uses no bandwidth when idle, except maybe a few bytes every so often (default is 2 hours) if "keep-alive" is enabled.

500 connections is nothing, though `epoll()` is a good choice to reduce system overhead.  5000 connections might start to become an issue.

Comment: With my testing so far, ive reached 15k connections with a single server, with what appears to be 0.1% cpu usage. Where should i look for issues that start at 5k?

Comment: Nothing special at 5k; I just picked it at 10x the original number as an example of how insignificant "500 connections" is to a modern machine.

Answer (score 0):

Bandwidth isn't your major concern, but there's a limit to the number of connections you can have open (though it is quite high).

But if polling every 15 seconds would be fast enough, I'd consider it a waste to keep the connection open.

Comment: A waste of what? The overhead of connecting every 15 seconds for 500 clients will cause more data to be sent than just leaving the connection open and sending a keep alive every 2 hours.

Comment: If it stays at 500, maybe, but MMOGs may grow beyond that quickly. But of course, by that time a couple of additional servers will be needed anyway, if OP will even come that far. With the amount of reasearch that appears to have been done so far, I doubt if this will become the new WOW.